How to Use CUDA Graphs with Interdependent Streams and Dynamic Parameters?
I have a CUDA program with multiple interdependent streams, and I want to convert it to use CUDA graphs to reduce launch overhead and improve performance. My program involves launching three kernels (kernel1, kernel2, and kernel3) across two streams (stream1 and stream2), with dependencies managed using CUDA events (event1 and event2). The parameters for these kernels are dynamic and need to be updated at each iteration.
In particular, the dynamic parameters include:

A matrix that changes for each iteration.
An array that is populated during each iteration, where the next iteration uses the previous value of that array.
The iteration variable i.

Here is the simplified structure of my code:
cudaStream_t stream1, stream2;
cudaEvent_t event1, event2;

for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
        kernel1<<<1, 512, 0, stream1>>>(i, dynamic_parameters);
        kernel2<<<1, 512, 0, stream2>>>(i, dynamic_parameters);
        kernel3<<<1, 512, 0, stream1>>>(i, dynamic_parameters);
        cudaEventRecord(event1, stream2);
        cudaEventRecord(event2, stream1);
    } else {
        cudaStreamWaitEvent(stream1, event1, 0);
        kernel1<<<1, 512, 0, stream1>>>(i, dynamic_parameters);
        cudaStreamWaitEvent(stream2, event2, 0);
        kernel2<<<1, 512, 0, stream2>>>(i, dynamic_parameters);
        cudaEventRecord(event1, stream2);
        kernel3<<<1, 512, 0, stream1>>>(i, dynamic_parameters);
        cudaEventRecord(event2, stream1);
    }
}

I've read NVIDIA blogs Employing CUDA Graphs in a Dynamic Environment and Constructing CUDA Graphs with Dynamic Parameters, but I couldn't figure out how to do it.
Specifically, I am struggling with:

Capturing the interdependent streams into a single CUDA graph.
Correctly handling the dynamic parameters (i, the changing matrix, and the array) in the graph.
Ensuring the dependencies (managed by event1 and event2) are respected within the graph.

Here's an outline of what I've tried so far to convert the else part to use CUDA graphs:
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <vector>

// Assume these kernel functions are defined 
__global__ void kernel1(int i, int* static_params, int* dynamic_params);
__global__ void kernel2(int i, int* static_params, int* dynamic_params);
__global__ void kernel3(int i, int* dynamic_params);

void execute_kernels_with_graphs(int* matrix, int* array, int m, int n, int* static_params, int* dynamic_params) {
    cudaStream_t stream1, stream2;
    cudaEvent_t event1, event2;
    cudaGraph_t capturedGraph;
    cudaGraphExec_t graphExec;
    std::vector<cudaGraphNode_t> node_list;

    cudaStreamCreate(&stream1);
    cudaStreamCreate(&stream2);
    cudaEventCreate(&event1);
    cudaEventCreate(&event2);

    bool capturingGraph = true;
    bool updatingGraph = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            kernel1<<<1, 512, 0, stream1>>>(i, static_params, dynamic_params);
            kernel2<<<1, 512, 0, stream2>>>(i, static_params, dynamic_params);
            kernel3<<<1, 512, 0, stream1>>>(i, dynamic_params);
            cudaEventRecord(event1, stream2);
            cudaEventRecord(event2, stream1);
        } else {
            if (capturingGraph) {
                // Start capturing the graph
                cudaStreamBeginCapture(stream1, cudaStreamCaptureModeGlobal);

                // Wait for event and launch kernels
                cudaStreamWaitEvent(stream1, event1, 0);
                kernel1<<<1, 512, 0, stream1>>>(i, dynamic_params);
                cudaStreamWaitEvent(stream2, event2, 0);
                kernel2<<<1, 512, 0, stream2>>>(i, dynamic_params);
                cudaEventRecord(event1, stream2);
                kernel3<<<1, 512, 0, stream1>>>(i, dynamic_params);
                cudaEventRecord(event2, stream1);

                // Get the current stream capturing graph
                cudaStreamCaptureStatus capture_status;
                const cudaGraphNode_t* deps;
                size_t dep_count;
                cudaStreamGetCaptureInfo_v2(stream1, &capture_status, nullptr, &capturedGraph, &deps, &dep_count);

                // Manually add kernel nodes with dynamic parameters
                cudaGraphNode_t new_node;
                cudaKernelNodeParams dynamic_params_cuda = {};
                dynamic_params_cuda.func = (void*)kernel1;
                dynamic_params_cuda.gridDim = dim3(1);
                dynamic_params_cuda.blockDim = dim3(512);
                dynamic_params_cuda.sharedMemBytes = 0;
                dynamic_params_cuda.kernelParams = (void**)&dynamic_params;

                cudaGraphAddKernelNode(&new_node, capturedGraph, deps, dep_count, &dynamic_params_cuda);
                node_list.push_back(new_node);

                dynamic_params_cuda.func = (void*)kernel2;
                dynamic_params_cuda.gridDim = dim3(1);
                dynamic_params_cuda.kernelParams = (void**)&dynamic_params;
                cudaGraphAddKernelNode(&new_node, capturedGraph, deps, dep_count, &dynamic_params_cuda);
                node_list.push_back(new_node);

                dynamic_params_cuda.func = (void*)kernel3;
                dynamic_params_cuda.gridDim = dim3(1);
                dynamic_params_cuda.kernelParams = (void**)&dynamic_params;
                cudaGraphAddKernelNode(&new_node, capturedGraph, deps, dep_count, &dynamic_params_cuda);
                node_list.push_back(new_node);

                // End the capture and instantiate the graph
                cudaStreamEndCapture(stream1, &capturedGraph);
                cudaGraphInstantiate(&graphExec, capturedGraph, nullptr, nullptr, 0);

                capturingGraph = false;
                updatingGraph = true;
            } else if (updatingGraph) {
                // Update the dynamic parameters of the kernel nodes in the graph
                cudaKernelNodeParams dynamic_params_updated_cuda = {};
                dynamic_params_updated_cuda.func = (void*)kernel1;
                dynamic_params_updated_cuda.gridDim = dim3(1);
                dynamic_params_updated_cuda.blockDim = dim3(512);
                dynamic_params_updated_cuda.sharedMemBytes = 0;
                dynamic_params_updated_cuda.kernelParams = (void**)&dynamic_params;

                cudaGraphExecKernelNodeSetParams(graphExec, node_list[0], &dynamic_params_updated_cuda);

                dynamic_params_updated_cuda.func = (void*)kernel2;
                dynamic_params_updated_cuda.gridDim = dim3(1);
                dynamic_params_updated_cuda.kernelParams = (void**)&dynamic_params;
                cudaGraphExecKernelNodeSetParams(graphExec, node_list[1], &dynamic_params_updated_cuda);

                dynamic_params_updated_cuda.func = (void*)kernel3;
                dynamic_params_updated_cuda.gridDim = dim3(1);
                dynamic_params_updated_cuda.kernelParams = (void**)&dynamic_params;
                cudaGraphExecKernelNodeSetParams(graphExec, node_list[2], &dynamic_params_updated_cuda);
            }

            // Execute the graph
            cudaGraphLaunch(graphExec, stream1);
        }
    }

    cudaStreamSynchronize(stream1);
    cudaStreamSynchronize(stream2);

    cudaStreamDestroy(stream1);
    cudaStreamDestroy(stream2);
    cudaEventDestroy(event1);
    cudaEventDestroy(event2);
    cudaGraphDestroy(capturedGraph);
    cudaGraphExecDestroy(graphExec);
}


Despite following these steps, I'm unsure if I'm capturing the interdependent streams and dynamic parameters correctly. Can someone guide me on how to achieve this effectively using CUDA graphs?

When capturing, you need kind of a "root" node. for example, capturing stream 1 but then waiting on stream 2 via event results in your error unless there is an initial dependency between stream 2 and stream 1

@AbatorAbetor I didn't understand , can you write your explanation as an answer

@Photos Look at the example in Cross-stream Dependencies and Events. You are missing the cudaEventRecord() and cudaStreamWaitEvent() as a fork of stream2 from stream1. A graph can't have two independent streams coming in (it is only watching the one stream passed to cudaStreamBeginCapture) without this kind of fork point.

Given the amount of iterations and no indication of the loop being run multiple times with the same arguments, my previous recommendation of capturing the whole loop was misguided in terms of performance optimization. I removed the comment to avoid further confusion. Using the new Conditional WHILE Node to put the whole loop onto the GPU without having to create a giant graph is still a valid and potentially performant idea, I think.

I am ignoring the specific code you posted and trying to address the main challenge:

The parameters for these kernels are dynamic and need to be updated at each iteration.

One possible approach is to replace "call dynamism" with data dynamism:
Specifically:

Suppose your dynamic parameters are of types param1_t and param2_t.
Define struct dynamic_params_t { param1_t param1; param2_t param2; }
Allocate sizeof(dynamic_params_t) as managed memory (before creating/capturing the CUDA graph)
Have the kernels take a dynamic_params_t const * __restrict parameter - that address of the piece of memory you allocated.
Read the actual parameters via the pointer.
Use cudaStreamAddCallback to schedule the CPU-side code which updates the call arguments.
Use events to make sure the argument-setting code is executed after the previous call and before the next.

(The new events and callback should be captured in the graph).

If you're not familiar with managed memory, read Unified Memory for CUDA Beginners, and then use one of the following for the allocation:

cudaMallocManaged()
cuMemAllocManaged() (if you're using the driver API, which it looks like you aren't)
cuda::memory::managed::allocate() (using my own modern-C++ wrappers)
cuda::memory::managed::make_unique_span() (using my own  modern-C++ wrappers; this is a RAII class which you don't need to manually free on your own).



I am ignoring the specific code you posted and trying to address the main challenge:

The parameters for these kernels are dynamic and need to be updated at each iteration.

You can use the mechanism for setting parameters in CUDA graph instances, and specifically, this function:
_host__ ​cudaError_t cudaGraphExecKernelNodeSetParams ( 
    cudaGraphExec_t hGraphExec, 
    cudaGraphNode_t node, 
    const cudaKernelNodeParams* pNodeParams 
);

So, no more capturing for you... you construct the graph vertices and edges "manually" for the first loop iteration (i = 0), using the graph API - and save the cudaGraphNode_t handles for your three kernel launch nodes, as well as the cudaKernelNodeParams structures you used for the three kernels (with the cudaGraphAddKernelNode() function). Note that in those structures, kernel arguments are set using an array of void-pointers.
You then instantiate the graph, and start your loop over i.
At each loop iteration, you construct an array of void pointers, pointing at the i'th iteration's arguments for each of your kernels; you set the cudaKernelNodeParams::kernelParams field to that array, and call cudaGraphExecKernelNodeSetParams() - to commit the update to CUDA's graph instance. You then launch the instance like in your existing code (but once in each iteration).
